# Reuse LINQ's SELECT (When querying to tables with the same signature)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, expression

How can I simplify this LINQ query? I'm interested in using Expression or something for the select part. (Maybe it is possible for the where clause as well?)

```
(from t1 in ctx.Table1 
where t1.SomeColumn == "Whatever"
 select new MyType 
 {
  Id = t1.Id,
   Name = t1.Name
 }).Union(
     from t2 in ctx.Table2 
     where t2.SomeColumn == "Whatever"
 select new MyType 
 {
  Id = t2.Id,
   Name = t2.Name
 });
```

Comment: nothing, this re-use stuff is new for me.

Comment: It looks like the types for `t1` and `t2` are different (even though they share similar columns) so "reusing" the delegates would require creating a common interface for their types and applying it to your entity classes.